# geodesics / shortest curve between orthogonal points / parameter representation

Tags: differential-geometry

sorry if this question seems trivial since i barely have any knowledge about differential geometry.

Let $\boldsymbol{x}_1, \boldsymbol{x}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $||\boldsymbol{x}_i||=1$, $i=1,2$, $\quad \boldsymbol{x}_1^T\boldsymbol{x}_2=0$

is the shortest curve on the unit sphere $S_{d-1}:=\{\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d:||\boldsymbol{x}||=1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ between $\boldsymbol{x}_1, \boldsymbol{x}_2$ simply
$\gamma(t):=\sqrt{t}\boldsymbol{x}_1 + \sqrt{1-t}\boldsymbol{x}_2$ ?
And is there any bijective mapping (any stereographic mapping by choosing the polar point properly maybe) from $S_{d-1}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ such that $\gamma(t)$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$

Edit: forgot to say that $\boldsymbol{x}_1$ should be orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{x}_2$

Comment: Your curve does not lie on the unit sphere. You want to parametrize the arc of the great circle with appropriate trig functions. Stereographic projection from the north pole will always map circles through the pole to lines.

Comment: P.S. The fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are orthogonal makes this parametrization very simple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TedShifrin, I dont understand why my curve does not lie on the unit sphere, is it not sufficient, that ||gamma(t)||^2=t*||x_1||^2+(1-t)*||x_2||^2+sqrt(t)*sqrt(1-t)*x_1^T x_2 = 1? for all t in [0,1]?

Comment: The reason for my question is that I have an minimization algorithm (under the constraint ||x||=1) and I iteratively set the derivative of gamma equal zero and I hoped to get a convergence proof by changing to the unrestricted space R^{d-1} where convergence results for such line search algorithms exist but I lack the knowledge in differential geometry unfortunately

Comment: Oh, I apologize. You are correct. I'm just so used to using the "usual" parametrization of a circle with $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$. I don't think you need much differential geometry here, because, as you pointed out, you can parametrize (most of) the sphere easily enough by a plane. It's not clear to me whether you need a particularly "nice" parametrization, but stereographic projection will, as you pointed out, send circles to circles and lines.

Comment: So assume I have a (hopefully stationary) point x_1 and an objective function f:S_d-1 -> R and I know d/dt f(gamma(t)) =0 for any direction (x_2) orthogonal to x_1.
Let g be the stereographic projection such that g^-1(gamma(t)) is a line. Can I conclude somehow grad(f(g(v)))^T d =0 for v=g^-1(x_1) for all d in R^{d-1}

Thanks a lot for any Ideas